# How to obtain conditioned results from an R dataframe

Tags: r, edx

This is my first message here. I'm trying to solve an R exercise from an edX R course, and I'm stuck in it. It would be great if somebody could help me solve it. Here are the dataframe and question given:

```
> students
   height shoesize gender population
1     181       44   male     kuopio
2     160       38 female     kuopio
3     174       42 female     kuopio
4     170       43   male     kuopio
5     172       43   male     kuopio
6     165       39 female     kuopio
7     161       38 female     kuopio
8     167       38 female    tampere
9     164       39 female    tampere
10    166       38 female    tampere
11    162       37 female    tampere
12    158       36 female    tampere
13    175       42   male    tampere
14    181       44   male    tampere
15    180       43   male    tampere
16    177       43   male    tampere
17    173       41   male    tampere
```

> Given the dataframe above, create two subsets with students whose height is equal to or below the median height (call it *students.short*) and students whose height is strictly above the median height (call it *students.tall*). What is the mean shoesize for each of the above 2 subsets by population?

I've been able to create the two subsets *students.tall* and *students.short* (both display the answers by `TRUE/FALSE`), but I don't know how to obtain the mean by population. The data should be displayed like this:

```
                    kuopio     tampere
students.short      xxxx       xxxx
students.tall       xxxx       xxxx
```

Many thanks if you can give me a hand!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `split` by a logical vector based on the `median` height

```
# // median height
medHeight <- median(students$height, na.rm = TRUE)

# // split the data into a list of data.frames using the 'medHeight'
lst1 <- with(students, split(students, height > medHeight))
```

Then loop over the `list` use `aggregate` from `base R`

```
lapply(lst1, function(dat) aggregate(shoesize ~ population, 
        data = dat, FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

However, we don't need to create two separate datasets or a `list`.  It can be done by grouping with both 'population' and the 'grp' created with `logical` vector

```
library(dplyr)
students %>%
     group_by(grp = height > medHeight, population) %>%
     summarise(shoesize = mean(shoesize))
```

Comment: ¡Many thanks, akrun! The code shows the data in a different table than the one proposed by the exercise, but it helped me to know the answer.

Comment: @Kai7 you could create two objects with `list2env` wrapping on the `lst1`, but I wouldn't recommend to create multiple objects in the global env i.e. `names(lst1) <- c('shortdat', 'longdat'); list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
#Code
students.short <- students[students$height<=median(students$height),]
students.tall <- students[students$height>median(students$height),]
#Mean
mean(students.short$shoesize)
mean(students.tall$shoesize)
```

Output:

```
[1] 38.44444
[1] 42.75
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pivot_wider()` in `tidyr` and set the argument `values_fn` as `mean`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(grp = if_else(height > median(height), "students.tall", "students.short")) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = grp, names_from = population, values_from = height, values_fn = mean)

# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#   grp            kuopio tampere
#   <chr>           <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 students.tall    176.    177.
# 2 students.short   164     163.
```

---

With a `base` way, you can try `xtabs()`, which returns a `table` object.

```
xtabs(height ~ grp + population,
      aggregate(height ~ grp + population, FUN = mean,
                transform(df, grp = ifelse(height > median(height), "students.tall", "students.short"))))

#                 population
# grp                kuopio  tampere
#   students.short 164.0000 163.4000
#   students.tall  175.6667 177.2000
```

***Note:*** *To convert a `table` object into `data.frame`, you can use `as.data.frame.matrix()`.*